# New VPS iptables are different?

Tags: centos, iptables

I got a new VPS with a new company and all that.

Anyway when I try to edit /etc/sysconfig/iptables the file is empty!

What should I do? I want to import my old iptable settings to open some ports...

I am running centOS 6...I will be going from 5.7

Also my old server was a dedicated server if that makes any difference.

Any ideas?

I installed CentOS 5.6 and iptables didn't even exist...the config did but not the file iptables...so I created it and it seems to be working fine when I do iptables -L

but I try to do a restart so they'll take affect and I get this error

Flushing firewall rules: [ OK ]
Setting chains to policy ACCEPT: security raw nat mangle fi[FAILED]
Unloading iptables modules: [ OK ]
Applying iptables firewall rules: [ OK ]

Has anyone else ever had this issue, how should I go about fixing it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
iptables-save > rules.txt
```

to dump the rules to a text file.

Then, you can use:

```
iptables-restore rules.txt
```

to activate these rules.

Comment: Ok I did that but when I try restarting iptables I get this


iptables: Setting chains to policy ACCEPT: security raw nat[FAILED]filter

Comment: How did you restart iptables? Did you overwrite the empty file `/etc/sysconfig/iptables`?

Comment: service iptables restart is what I did. But it seems "iptables-restore rules.txt" did nothing. Should I just copy paste them in...

One thing I did notice is the iptables file doesn't even exist, it wants to make one.

Comment: @JosipGòdlyZirdum: Yes, you need to create one and fill it with your rules. Then, `service iptables restart`.

Comment: I did it and it seems ok but when I try restarting it I get this 
"Setting chains to policy ACCEPT: security raw nat mangle fi[FAILED]"

Comment: The google said when looking for "Setting chains to policy ACCEPT: security raw nat mangle" that the error has something to do with CentOS 6; that's all I read since I got no clue about CentOS 6, but you might give that a whirl.

Comment: I had centos 6 but I put on 5.6 now. So that doesn't really help =/